# Consolidating JSON Data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to sort through every file in a directory, read the json data, decode it, put it in an array, and then write it all to a new file.

The problem I'm running into is the resulting array is just an array of arrays of json data, it seems.

Here's my code:

```
    $AllAppointmentDataFileName = 'AllAppointmentData.jsonp';
    $AllAppointmentDataURL = '../Appointments/' . $AllAppointmentDataFileName;
    if ($handle = opendir('../Appointments')) {

        while ( false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)) ) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && $entry != $AllAppointmentDataFileName) {

                $AllAppointmentData .= json_decode(file_get_contents('../Appointments/' . $entry));

                print_r($AllAppointmentData); echo "<br>";

                echo "$entry:<br>" . file_get_contents('../Appointments/' . $entry) . "<br>";
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }

    file_put_contents($AllAppointmentDataURL, json_encode($AllAppointmentData));
```

The print_r just returns "Array."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.=` operator is for string concatenation; it is not for adding an element to an array.

You should be using `[] =` instead:

```
$AllAppointmentData[] = json_decode(file_get_contents('../Appointments/' . $entry));
```

If your files contain arrays that you want merged into a single array, you can use a foreach loop:

```
$curAppointmentData = json_decode(file_get_contents('../Appointments/' . $entry));
foreach ($curAppointmentData as $obj) {
    $AllAppointmentData[] = $obj;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the reason `print_r` prints "Array" is because the array resulting from the `json_decode` is casted to a string.

Comment: Alright. I changed that. Now, in my json file, it leads with '`[[`', as there are two files. Is that still considered proper JSON format (that would be readable by any JSON decoder/reader)? I think the format currently is `[[{"Name":"Value","Name":"Value"}][{"Name":"Value","Name":"Value"}]]`

Comment: @Jamil: Aside from a missing comma between the two arrays, yes, that is valid JSON.